# Не останавливается таймер

Tags: c#, .net, таймер

У меня есть метод для вызова нужной анимации:

```
public static void Add(Form it, bool enabled, int type, double time, int interval)
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    if (enabled == true)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case 1:
                it.Opacity = 1;
                timer.Tick += new EventHandler((sender, e) =>
                {
                    if ((it.Opacity -= time) == 0) { timer.Stop(); }
                    else if (it.Opacity == 0)
                    {
                        Get(timer);
                    }
                });
                timer.Interval = interval;
                timer.Start();
                break;
            case 2:
                it.Opacity = 0;
                timer.Tick += new EventHandler((sender, e) =>
                {
                    if ((it.Opacity += time) == 1) { timer.Stop(); }
                    else if (it.Opacity == 1)
                    {
                        Get(timer);
                    }
                });
                timer.Interval = interval;
                timer.Start();
                break;
            case 3:
                it.Opacity = 1;
                double i = 0;
                timer.Tick += new EventHandler((sender, e) =>
                {
                    if ((i += time) == 1) { timer.Stop(); }
                    else if (i == 1)
                    {
                        Get(timer);
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                });
                timer.Interval = interval;
                timer.Start();
                break;
        }
    }
}

private static void Get(Timer timer)
{
    timer.Stop();
    Action.Get = true;
}
```

Первые две анимации работают. А третья нет.
Суть третьей анимации такова: при достижении переменной `i` значения `1`, форма должна закрыться и открыть другую.
Я вывел переменную `i` в консоль и увидел, что `i` меняется на `+0.05` до бесконечности, то есть таймер при достижении `1` не останавливается.
Помогите решить проблему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// накопленная ошибка операций с плавающей точкой
if ((i += time) >= 1) { timer.Stop(); }
```